# c# regex: parse last table from text file

Tags: c#, regex

So i have `Text` file that i am read, inside this file i have this kind of table:

```
My data Statistics:
=============================================================
Bla bla                                           : 120
Bla bla bla bla                                   : 1
Number of files                                   : 1
Size                                              : 1
Total                                             : 1
```

This table exist many times inside the `Text` and i am read this table this way:

```
StreamReader reader...
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, "My data Statistics:");
```

Now i want to take the Last table inside the file:

```
int count = matches.Count;
Match match = matches[count - 1];
```

And from here I need your help:

What is the best way to read the table and parse my table according to the string and the value, for example:

In the first line string is `Bla bla` and the value is `120`

Comment: What have you tried and what was wrong with it

Comment: I did not a way to iterate over my table after i found it

Comment: So, show the code you used to read the file, and find the table.... make a start..

Comment: I already have it: this is the match i post, now after i have the last table in my file how to parse it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple demo program to explain one possibility how to do this. First of all I think there are some mistakes in your demo code.
When you say, you need to find the last table in the text. I dont understand how you use the Regex to find this position.

I tried to explain the code by comments.
Have fun.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  // Text as member here
  private static readonly string Text = "My data Statistics:\n" +
                                        "=============================================================\n" +
                                        "Bla bla                                           : 120\n" +
                                        "Bla bla bla bla                                   : 1\n" +
                                        "Number of files                                   : 1\n" +
                                        "Size                                              : 1\n" +
                                        "Total                                             : 1\n" + "\n";

  // Define how to now when a table starts and when it ends


  // Table starts when line is "My data Statistics:"
  private static readonly string TableStartMarker = "My data Statistics:";
  // Table ends when line is empty??? Not specified in question
  private static readonly string TableEndMarker = "";

  public static void Main()
  {
    //  Split text by \n to get lines
    var lines = new List<string>(Text.Split('\n'));
    // Find last line where content is the TableStartMarker (My data statistics... 
    var lastTableStart = lines.FindLastIndex(x => x == TableStartMarker);

    //Iterate over all lines starting from last table header
    foreach (var line in lines.Skip(lastTableStart))
    {
      // if line is empty -> table has endend
      if (line == TableEndMarker)
        return;

      //now we have content -> split by :
      var split = line.Split(':');
      if (split.Length < 2)
        continue;

      //remove whitespaces and there you go: key and value
      var key = split[0].TrimEnd();
      var value = split[1].TrimStart();
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, value));
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I corrected it.     `var lastTableStart = lines.FindLastIndex(x => x == TableStartMarker);` FindLastIndex instead of FindIndex